# Mounting ConfigMap deleted old data from MySQL my.cnf file

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am a newbee in Kubernetes/Openshift.

I am trying to update MySQL configuration using configmap. I have the below yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: slave-replcmap
data:
  my.conf: |
    [mysqld]
    server-id=2
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-slave
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql-slave
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql-slave
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: slave-mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: slave-nfs-claim1
        - name: slave-replcmap-vol
          configMap:
            name: slave-replcmap
        - name: slave-mysqlinitconf-vol
          configMap:
            name: slave-mysqlinitcmap
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.7
        name: mysql-slave
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_SERVER_CONTAINER
          value: mysql
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mysql-secret
                key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mysql-secret
                key: MYSQL_DATABASE
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mysql-secret
                key: MYSQL_USER
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mysql-secret
                key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql-slave
        volumeMounts:
        - name: slave-mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
        - name: slave-mysqlinitconf-vol
          mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        - name: slave-replcmap-vol
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/my.cnf
          subPath: my.conf
```

Its updating the config file no issues in that.

But the issue is its deleting the existing content from my.cnf file and adding configmap data. I need to append this configmap data to my.cnf file without deleting the existing data.

Please let me know how i have to modify the yml file for to achieve that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot preserve data in the file,but you can use additional file with required configuration using the following syntax: !include /path/to/my/file/my2.cnf

Comment: Thank you for your time, I didn't get it completely. Should i create a new file in that path?

Comment: Here you can do the following. Set up MYSQL_HOME [variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html) where your custom mysql.cnf file will be stored and include the second file with other options into it as it was described above. In this case, server will be started with my.cnf file using path specified in MYSQL_HOME env variable. Additionally you can read an article with all variables which might be useful for you.

Comment: hope you are giving the solution for kubernetes world container...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current configuration mount volume directly to `my.cnf` file - `mountPath: /etc/mysql/my.cnf`. When you are doing that you are replacing it. `subPath` property is used to reference the file by key. Similar example can be found [here](https://carlos.mendible.com/2019/02/10/kubernetes-mount-file-pod-with-configmap/).

Ive deployed this image on my local env. As default `my.cnf` inside have only some commented text and:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

It means that all configuration files from both folders are included in main configuration.

Instead of mounting main config you might mount this config to one of the folders. For example:

```
...
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d/new.conf
          subPath: my.conf
```

Ohter ways how to pass `ConfigMaps` are describe [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).

I would also recommended you to check this [MySQL HELM Chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mysql#custom-mysql-configuration-files) about configuration files in `MySQL`.

Comment: I solved this, you should have same name in mountPath and subPath(new.conf/my.conf these should be same else it don't work.)

Comment: @Abdul Ive tested it on `Minikube` (maybe Openshift works diferently). `mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d/new.conf` means that it will create `new.conf` inside `conf.d` directory.  `subPath` value must be the same as value in `data` from `ConfigMap`.
Anyway I'm glad Its working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, the default `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` includes the following folder: `/etc/mysql/conf.d/`. So if you place your custom configuration in files in that folder, you are good.

You can achieve this with a ConfigMap as you propose.

Start by creating a ConfigMap:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql-custom-config
data:
  my.custom.conf: |
    [mysqld]
    server-id=2
```

As you can see from the example, this ConfigMap contains a single file named `my.custom.conf`.

Next, map this file to a file under `/etc/mysql/conf.d/`:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - image: mysql:5.7
    name: mysql
    ...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: mysql-custom-config
      mountPath: /etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.my.cnf
      subPath: custom.my.cnf #should be the name used in the ConfigMap
  volumes:
  - name: mysql-custom-config
    configMap:
      name: mysql-custom-config
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe the content of existing my.cnf file is fixed .Thus you can add the existing content of my.cnf file to your configmap .

Answer (score 0):

the way i did is super simple we need to create my.cnf on local machine then in next step we need to create configmap then we can mount

Here are the steps
**Step 1 : create my.cnf local**

```
controlplane ~ ➜  cat my.cnf 
[mysqld]
port=3306
confdir=conf.d/
```

Step 2 : Create Configmap

```
controlplane ~ ➜  kubectl create configmap mycnf --from-file=my.cnf
```

Step : Update pods definition file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: mysql
  name: mysql
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: mysql
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/etc/my.cnf"
      subPath: my.cnf
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    configMap:
      name: mycnf
```

> Same will work for deployment statefulsets daemonsets just ensure with indentation